# Windows 10 doesn't remember different RDP auth for different port numbers

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, security, remote-desktop

I have various RDP configurations pointing to workstations on the same target connection, but using different port numbers.  I swear Windows 7 could save different passwords with the connections on different ports.  Windows 10 does not and it's and now it's an annoying, time-consuming thing to click through the "use other login" click-path and enter new credentials... which then aren't remembered the next time it needs to be changed again.

I tried entering the credentials manually, including the port numbers (eg.: "machine-name:1234") in the Windows Credential Manager and it still doesn't work.

Is there a trick to getting Windows 10 to actually save the credentials properly for RDP configurations to the same connection with different port numbers?